# Finding elements with fluid xpaths with selenium

Tags: html, css, selenium

From the following HTML code, I am trying to select `<input class="cs-autocomplete-input" tabindex="">` using Selenium WebDriver, however, I can't seem to be able to because the elements have fluid IDs. How can I go about finding elements such as these? I can't use `By.className("cs-autocomplete-input")` because there are multiple items with that class name in the web page.

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="fluid-id-bhlpjo3p-1026">
        <input type="button" class="csc-repeatable-add-bhlpjo3p-1022 cs-repeatable-add" value="+">
        <ul class="cs-repeatable">
            <li class="csc-repeatable-repeat-bhlpjo3p-1022 clearfix cs-repeatable-repeat show">
                <input type="radio" class="csc-repeatable-primary-bhlpjo3p-1022 show cs-repeatable-primary" name="primary-fields.sponsors" value="true">
                <input type="text" class="csc-exhibition-sponsor cs-repeatable-content" id="repeat::.csc-exhibition-sponsor" name="repeat::.csc-exhibition-sponsor" style="display: none;">
                <input class="cs-autocomplete-input" tabindex="">
                <a href="#" class="cs-autocomplete-closebutton" title="Cancel edit, and return this field to the most recent authority value" style="display: none;"></a>
                <input type="button" value="" class="csc-repeatable-delete-bhlpjo3p-1022 cs-repeatable-delete" disabled="">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Not sure if this is helpful but this div's xpath is
`//*[@id="primaryTab"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
browser.findElement(By.id("primaryTag")).findElement(By.cssSelector(".cs-autocomplete-input[tabindex='']"))
```

Here is the CSS in action.

```css
#someId .my-input[tabindex=''] {
  background: red;
}

/* styles for example readability — ignore */
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="someId">
  <input class="my-input" tabindex="3" type="text" value='not me' />
  <input class="my-input" tabindex="3" type="text" value='not me' />
  <input class="my-input" tabindex="" type="text" value=' me' />
  <input class="my-input" tabindex="3" type="text" value='not me' />
  <input class="my-input" tabindex="" type="text" value='me' />
</div>
```